# VDHL sfixed decoding code does not work properly

Tags: vhdl, fpga, fixed-point, intel-fpga

I am using **David bishop's fixed point library** to do some math in vhdl. and i need to decode the final value into integers. the method i have followed as below, and i do get fine value for fractional part but the decimal value is not correct. i could not find the issue yet. in decimal part 1st two digits are wrong. **xx**8374.839923 **xx** numbers are wrong always.

when i perform this,  i get **2**74334.738295 for **1**74334.738295

inside architecture,
inside process i do declare these variables,

```
variable  cp : sfixed(20 downto -19);
variable mod10 : sfixed(4 downto 0);
variable div10 : sfixed(4 downto 0);

variable L0 : sfixed(4 downto 0);
variable L1 : sfixed(4 downto -4);
variable L2 : sfixed(4 downto -8);
variable L3 : sfixed(4 downto -12);
variable L4 : sfixed(4 downto -16);
variable L5 : sfixed(4 downto -20);
variable L6 : sfixed(4 downto -24); 

variable    temp_L  : sfixed(19 downto 0);
variable    temp_L1 : sfixed(20 downto -4);
variable    temp_L2 : sfixed(21 downto -8);
variable    temp_L3 : sfixed(22 downto -12);
variable    temp_L4 : sfixed(23 downto -16);
variable    temp_L5 : sfixed(24 downto -20);
variable    temp_L6 : sfixed(25 downto -24);
```

after begin, i need to decode 174334.738295 in sfixed, because some times i get negative number. this number is to replaced by another calculation, which is not provided here, if that number is 174334.738295 (sfixed) then i need to decode this number,

```
cp      :=  to_sfixed(174334.738295,20,-19);
temp_L  := cp(19 downto 0); -- remove sign bit

mod10   :=to_sfixed(10,4,0) ;                 
div10   :=to_sfixed(10,4,0) ;

L0      := temp_L mod mod10;
temp_L1 := temp_L/div10;
L1      := temp_L1 mod mod10;
temp_L2 := temp_L1/div10;
L2      := temp_L2 mod mod10;
temp_L3 := temp_L2/div10;
L3      := temp_L3 mod mod10;  
temp_L4 := temp_L3/div10;
L4      := temp_L4 mod mod10;               
temp_L5 := temp_L4/div10;
L5      := temp_L5 mod mod10;
temp_L6 := temp_L5/div10;
L6      := temp_L6 mod mod10;
```

L6 is the 1st digit and L5 is the 2nd digit.

Comment: I had no idea that negative indexes are possible. I wouldn't be using them, though.

Comment: @Oron Port please refer David Bishop's fixed point lib manual !

Comment: The fixed and floating point libraries are open source and stored at GitHub: https://github.com/fphdl/fphdl. You can open an issue there and ask for more detailed help. You should also compare your current copy with the latest version. This is by the way the version which will be released with VHDL-2017.

Comment: @Paebbels so you don't see any issue with the code?

Comment: There are issues with your code. It isn't an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you don't show how "xx8374.839923" is produced and there's a bit of coding to do to test it (entity, architecture and process or process and subprogram).  Using to_integer[sfixed return integer] is subject to rounding (and you don't demonstrate where the fixed_pkg is from nor it's rounding mode). Also mod10 and div10 aren't declared as variables, your code needs modification to analyze. Using no rounding and sfixed to_integer gives 174334 for the integer part. Provide an MCVE that replicates your result.

Comment: @user1155120 sorry my bad, i updated the code,  mod10 and div10 are sfixed, i used David Bishop's fixed point package, (currently i cannot find the source where i downloaded it)

Comment: @user1155120 when i use to_integer it gives integer part and it messed up the fractional part of my decoding. even when use to_integer with another copy of same cp variable (cp1:= cp;  -- used to fractional decoding).

Comment: Still not an MCVe. (Close enough to show it's a rounding error).

Comment: I wrote a comment to point you to potentially newer source files for the fixed and floating point packages written by David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying your original code with fixes for div10, mod10 (with underscores leaving the declarations alone) and producing an MCVE:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.fixed_pkg.all;

entity iopertyki is
end entity;

architecture fum of iopertyki is
begin
    process
        variable  cp:       sfixed(20 downto -19);
        variable mod_10:    sfixed(4 downto 0);
        variable div_10:    sfixed(4 downto 0);
        variable mul_10:    sfixed(4 downto 0); 

        variable L0:        sfixed(4 downto 0);
        variable L1:        sfixed(4 downto -4);
        variable L2:        sfixed(4 downto -8);
        variable L3:        sfixed(4 downto -12);
        variable L4:        sfixed(4 downto -16);
        variable L5:        sfixed(4 downto -20);
        variable L6:        sfixed(4 downto -24); 

        variable temp_L:    sfixed(19 downto 0);
        variable temp_L1:   sfixed(20 downto -4);
        variable temp_L2:   sfixed(21 downto -8);
        variable temp_L3:   sfixed(22 downto -12);
        variable temp_L4:   sfixed(23 downto -16);
        variable temp_L5:   sfixed(24 downto -20);
        variable temp_L6:   sfixed(25 downto -24);
    begin
        cp    :=  to_sfixed(174334.738295,20,-19);
        report "cp = " & to_string(cp);
        temp_L      := cp(19 downto 0); -- remove sign bit
        report "temp_L = " & to_string(temp_L);
        report "integer'image temp_L = " & integer'image(to_integer(temp_L));
        mod_10 := to_sfixed(10,4,0);                 
        div_10 := to_sfixed(10,4,0);
        mul_10 := to_sfixed(10,4,0);

        L0          := temp_L mod mod_10;
        temp_L1     := temp_L/div_10;
        L1          := temp_L1 mod mod_10;
        temp_L2     := temp_L1/div_10;
        L2          := temp_L2 mod mod_10;
        temp_L3     := temp_L2/div_10;
        L3          := temp_L3 mod mod_10; 
        temp_L4     := temp_L3/div_10;
        L4          := temp_L4 mod mod_10;              
        temp_L5     := temp_L4/div_10;
        L5          := temp_L5 mod mod_10;
        temp_L6     := temp_L5/div_10;
        L6          := temp_L6 mod mod_10; 
        -- xx8374.839923 ? 
        report " result   = " & integer'image(to_integer(L6)) &
                              integer'image(to_integer(L5)) &
                              integer'image(to_integer(L4)) &
                              integer'image(to_integer(L3)) &
                              integer'image(to_integer(L2)) &
                              integer'image(to_integer(L1)) &
                              integer'image(to_integer(L0));

        report " no round = " & integer'image(to_integer(L6(4 downto 0))) &
                              integer'image(to_integer(L5(4 downto 0))) &
                              integer'image(to_integer(L4(4 downto 0))) &
                              integer'image(to_integer(L3(4 downto 0))) &
                              integer'image(to_integer(L2(4 downto 0))) &
                              integer'image(to_integer(L1(4 downto 0))) &
                              integer'image(to_integer(L0(4 downto 0)));
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

This produces the integer part result (you don't demonstrate how you did this in your question, with the new results:

> ...get 274334.738295 for 174334.738295

You can demonstrate that to_integer rounding is responsible for L5 being 2 instead of 1:

> ```
> ghdl -a --std=08 iopertyki.vhdl
> ghdl -e --std=08 iopertyki
> ghdl -r iopertyki
>
> iopertyki.vhdl:91:9:@0ms:(report note): cp = 000101010100011111110.1011110100000000111
> iopertyki.vhdl:93:9:@0ms:(report note): temp_L = 00101010100011111110.0
> iopertyki.vhdl:94:9:@0ms:(report note): integer'image temp_L = 174334
> iopertyki.vhdl:113:9:@0ms:(report note):  result   = 0274334
> iopertyki.vhdl:121:9:@0ms:(report note):  no round = 0174334
> ```

So all this tells you to only use the integer part of L6 - L1 so there is no rounding. (There's a hint for how clipping an sfixed or ufixed value will work in David Bishop's user guide you commented on).

You could note that clipping an sfixed value will be subject to a sign bias and that you'd either need to change sign of all the recovered decimal digits or use signed magnitude (where your digit calculations might be ufixed) with the sign forwarded to the result for negative numbers. Math in decades can be cumbersome.

**Notes on elaboration and simulation when using ghdl**

There are three architectures of code generation for ghdl, using a GCC backend, an LLVM back end and an mcode just in time code generator.

From the newest [GHDL Documentation](http://ghdl.readthedocs.io/en/new-documentation-structure/index.html) section on [Invoking GHDL](http://ghdl.readthedocs.io/en/new-documentation-structure/using/InvokingGHDL.html) for the run command:

[run -r](http://ghdl.readthedocs.io/en/new-documentation-structure/using/InvokingGHDL.html#run-r)

> Runs/simulates a design. The options and arguments are the same as for
>   the elaboration command.
>
> - GGC/LLVM: simply, the filename of the executable is determined and it    is executed. Options are ignored. You may also directly execute
>     the    program. The executable must be in the current directory.
> - mcode: the design is elaborated and the simulation is launched. As a    consequence, you must use the same options used during analysis.

In an mcode version such as distributed for Win32 the -e elaborate command is redundant and the run command (-r) must include the same options as for the analysis command (-a).

For GCC/LLVM backend codegenerator versions of ghdl the elaborate (-e) command must have the same options as the analysis command (-a). For `--std=08` a different working library is used and any object files produced without the std option or with a different STD value will be overwritten if the library directory is not specified separately.

There are no object files for the mcode version. The analyzed objects only exist in the ghdl program's memory where the are subsequently elaborated with the run (-r) command into a simulation design model.

Without specifying versions or release the [ghdl](/questions/tagged/ghdl) user can only rely on ghdl documentation.

You could also note that [ghdl-0.34](https://github.com/tgingold/ghdl/releases/tag/GHDL-0.34) has been released in the last day and a Win32 binary image (mcode) and 64 bit binary image (llvm) are available (their names include "mingw").

Comment: can you tell me what is the simulator you have used?

Comment: how to include fixed point package to ghdl? i get error,  primary unit "fixed_pkg" not found in library "work"

Comment: `library ieee; use ieee.fixed_pkg.all;` with a command line option to use IEEE Std 1076-2008, e.g. ghdl -a --std=08. As shown in the example. As shown by a recent question here with the [tag:ghdl] tag options (e.g. --std=08) come after commands (-a).

Answer (score 0):

Your divisions should be integer divisions; they are not (fixed point divisions). And I do not even imagine what the modulus operator is supposed to return when applied to non integer (fixed point) arguments. Anyway, this fixed point representation is quite simple, so, if you just want the digits of the integer part of a positive fixed point number, you could first convert it to natural, and then compute the digits:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
...
variable n: natural;
subtype digit is natural range 0 to 9;
type digit_vector is array(natural range <>) of digits;
variable digits: digit_vector(5 downto 0);
...
n := to_integer(u_unsigned(cp(20 downto 0)));
for i in 0 to 5 loop
  digits(i) := n mod 10;
  n := n / 10;
end loop;
```

Or, if you simply want to print the decimal representation of `cp`:

```
use std.textio.all;
...
variable l: line;
...
write(l, to_integer(u_unsigned(cp(20 downto 0)));
writeline(output, n);
```

Or, even simpler, use the `write` procedure from the library itself:

```
variable tmp: sfixed(20 downto 0);
...
tmp := cp(20 downto 0);
write(l, tmp);
writeline(output, l);
```

Comment: i need to perform this for an sfixed variable.

Comment: I understood that and in my code `cp` is still an `sfixed`.

Comment: @ Renaud Pacalet to_unsigned cannot be used with sifxed right?Error (10381): indexed name returns a value whose type does not match "UNRESOLVED_ufixed", the type of the target expression

Comment: I am not using `to_unsigned`, I am using `u_unsigned` (the implicit conversion function). Is the error you show due to `to_unsigned` or `u_unsigned`?

Comment: just noticed, what is u_unsigned? is this from david bishop's fixed point lib? Error (10482): object "u_unsigned" is used but not declared

Comment: It is a type declared in `ieee.numeric_std` as indicated at the beginning of my example code.

Comment: I have included ieee.numeric_std but i get error when use **u_unsigned**

Comment: You must: 1) compile in VHDL2008 mode, 2) probably also use `ieee.std_logic_1164` (I add this to my answer).

Comment: i am using altera 16.1 Qurtus prime lite edition, i do not know how to compile in  VHDL2008 mode and  I have used ieee.std_logic_1164 but u_unsigned issue is still there.

Comment: You are not using a simulator, you are using a synthesizer. And unfortunately, most synthesizers are still not 100% vhdl2008 compatible. Use `unsigned ` instead of `u_unsigned` and it should work, this time. Beware: synthesizing divisions by 10 will probably pose some problems...

Comment: `u_unsigned` shall be preferred over `unsigned` for reasons that are too complex to be explained here, but as you apparently do not have the choice...

Comment: @RenaultPacalet Although I agree with you on some level on the use of unresolved types, I think you should watch out preaching them all the time. As you see here, you only give confusing advice that does not work for the T.S.

Comment: @JHBonarius: Sorry JH but I disagree. Using resolved types when it is not needed is bad. So, I always use unresolved types in the solutions I propose because I do not want to propose something bad.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Although there is truth in your statement, using resolved types has been industry standard for many decades. Also many books on VHDL give all examples using resolved types. As do tool vendor synthesis user guidelines. In a rough estimate, 99% of the VHDL code ever written probably uses resolved types. Including the IP included with most tools and sources like [OpenCores](http://opencores.org/cdn/downloads/opencores_coding_guidelines.pdf). And in this example, the synthesis tool doesn't support it in default settings.