# How to use "function" in VHDL to return multiple variables from the same calculation?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I am trying to implement a decoding code in a function to return multiple variables because, i have to decode two fixed point variables and i get an error for insufficient logic in fpga. so i need to perform decoding code as we do in c language--> call the function twice with two variables and get return in individual digits. is this possible to perform? if it is possible how to do it? or are there any other way to do this?

i am performing the code in below twice for two fixed points numbers 
and do the decoding for fractional part as well.decoding works fine for integer part and fractional part. 
after decoding i convert them to std_logic_vector and send to my lcd. that's why i decode the value. code is big around 1000 lines.
so i cannot put it here.

in the current code i perform twice same decoding so it makes big logic which fpga does not support. they work individually. so i need to put this once into a function and call the function twice.

[VDHL sfixed decoding code does not work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45596376/vdhl-sfixed-decoding-code-does-not-work-properly?noredirect=1&lq=1)

as the link code shows i get 6 variables for integer part and 6 variables for fractional part. i need to put this code in a function where it returns  12 variables.

Comment: Why don't you include some code that demonstrates your problem so that we can get a clear idea of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @scary_jeff  I have added the link that have part of the code that i am following

Comment: Convert the signed value to signed magnitude saving the sign. The integer and fraction parts can be viewed as two separate binary values. Use [double dabble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dabble) to create Binary Coded Decimal (BCD) digits. Use the BCD digits for each digit in the display pre-pending the sign and display the decimal point in the right place. As far as I recall you've never demonstrated the display method nor described the conversion rate or purpose.

Comment: "so i need to perform decoding code as we do in c language..." how come you think this is the solution? That is not how logic synthesis works. You are not programming a processor, you are describing configurable logic. If your code does not fit, you either need a larger FPGA, or you need to simplify your algorithm.

Comment: @JHBonarius yes i agree, i need to know how to simply algorithms in vhdl can you show me a link? or a book?

Comment: This is not the case of a simple link that will that will solve your problem. Writing FPGA specific DSP code is a specialism. People get paid big bucks to do it. You need to understand what is happening inside of the FPGA in order to meet timing and resource requirements. Apart from that you do not provide us with sufficient information about your algorithm to be able to help you, it would take us a lot of time and effort. This is not a simple coding question, it's a request for implementation support.

Comment: Function calls won't help with this : if you call the same function twice (e.g. in a loop in a clocked process) you'll get two instantiations of the hardware, just the same as if you drop in two components. (Essentially, in synthesis, loops are fully unrolled). Which means you'll still use too much resources. You'll need to sequentialise access to a single component - or function, either works - which typically requires a state machine to determine which task the component is executing at any time. It's not all that difficult buts @JHBonarius says it's a different mindset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the referenced question [VDHL sfixed decoding code does not work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45596376/vdhl-sfixed-decoding-code-does-not-work-properly?noredirect=1&lq=1) Renaud Pacalet commented in his answer [Your divisions should be integer divisions; they are not (fixed point divisions).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45596376/vdhl-sfixed-decoding-code-does-not-work-properly/45605857#45605857) there is no particular reason to be using signed fix point numbers in the actual conversion process, nor integers for that matter.

There's an algorithm ([Double dabble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dabble)) that uses shifts and 4 bit conditional adds that can be implemented in a loop statement. The one here is an expansion of the algorithm for 20 bit integer parts.

There's also a method of implementing an equivalent for the fractional part:

[Multi-Digit Binary to Decimal Converter (decimal fractions too!)](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/redstone-creations/352668-multi-digit-binary-to-decimal-converter-decimal"Multi-Digit Binary to Decimal Converter (decimal fractions too!)")

> An explanation of how the Algorithm works can be found on this website: http://www.johnloomis.org/ece314/notes/devices/binary_to_BCD/bin_to_bcd.html
>
> I went one step further though, and figured out how to apply the same principle to convert Binary Fractions to Decimal Fractions. For example, 0.11(bin) can be converted to 0.75(dec). by using conversion tables with that perform the inverse function (-3 if 8 or more) and shifting in the opposite direction.
>
> Last edited by Hans_Lemurson: Jun 9, 2012

While not implemented in a Minecraft game the fraction dabble involves a logic cell per comparison and subtraction just like double dabble does for addition.

The bits are shifted serially, double dabble is a multiplier, the fraction dabble is a divider.  The double dabble has a maximum number of add3 logic cells of 20 bits x 7 BCD digits (28 bits) or 140 logic cells. It's reduced by the number of cells that can't change the result, either based on not meeting the threshold (> 4) or guaranteed to have all '0' inputs. That ends up as 57 logic cells (each four 4x1 LUTs).

The fraction dabble uses more cells because shifting from the left immediately throws out thresholds for sub3 operations. The reduction following synthesis mapping from the 18 bits x 6 BCD digits or 108 sub3 cells 
only loses 6, giving a 102 logic cells.  The difference between an add3 and a sub3 is modulo four addition versus subtraction and a threshold of (> 4) versus (>7).

The number of logic cells could be reduced further (a lot further for the fraction dabble) by making the BCD value a clocked register and iterating 20 or 18 operations clock at a time. There would be a requirement for a state machine to handshake with inputs and outputs as well as iterate for the number of clocks representing the length of the binary input values.

The absolute value conversion is less than 40 logic cells.

The idea here is that using sequential operations bit at a time represents and performance vs. size trade off (noting you haven't specified the size of your present implementation using sfixed division and modulo reduction).

The following code implements the two dabbles as distinct functions which could be scaled for larger or smaller sfixed values and number of BCD digits and potentially be preceded with multiplexers as noted by Brian Drummond although it seems unlikely based on their sizes it's warranted.  (How big are the multiplexers?).

The implication of 'slower' performance is that you don't update the input values (shown as `cp` here) faster than the fall through time of the absolute value conversion concatenated with the longest time of the the two dabbles (the bigger one).

This code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.fixed_pkg.all;                    -- included in -2008

entity iopertyki is
end entity;

architecture fum of iopertyki is
    function doubledabble_20bit (inp:  std_logic_vector(19 downto 0)) 
            return unsigned is
        variable bin:   std_logic_vector(inp'range);
        variable bcd:   unsigned(27 downto 0);
    begin
        bin := inp;
        bcd := (others => '0');
        for i in 0 to 19 loop
            if bcd(3 downto 0) > 4 then
                bcd(3 downto 0) := bcd(3 downto 0) + 3;
            end if;
            if bcd(7 downto 4) > 4 then
                bcd(7 downto 4) := bcd(7 downto 4) + 3;
                end if;
            if bcd(11 downto 8) > 4 then
                bcd(11 downto 8) := bcd(11 downto 8) + 3;
            end if;
            if bcd(15 downto 12) > 4 then
                bcd(15 downto 12) := bcd(15 downto 12) + 3;
            end if;
            if bcd(19 downto 16) > 4 then
                bcd(19 downto 16) := bcd(19 downto 16) + 3;
            end if;
            if bcd(23 downto 20) > 4 then
                bcd(23 downto 20) := bcd(23 downto 20) + 3;
            end if;
            bcd := bcd(26 downto 0) & bin(19);
            bin := bin(18 downto 0) & '0';
        end loop;
        return bcd;
    end function;

    function fracdabble_19bit (inp:  std_logic_vector(18 downto 0)) 
            return unsigned is
        variable bin:   std_logic_vector(inp'range);
        variable bcd:   unsigned(23 downto 0);
        -- variable tbcd:  unsigned(23 downto 0); -- DEBUG
    begin
        bin := inp;
        bcd := (others => '0');                -- DEBUG
        for i in 0 to 18 loop

            bcd := bin(0) & bcd(23 downto 1);
            bin := '0' & bin(18 downto 1);
            -- tbcd := bcd;                       -- DEBUG

            if bcd(3 downto 0) > 7 then
                bcd(3 downto 0) := bcd(3 downto 0) - 3;
            end if;
            if bcd(7 downto 4) > 7 then
                bcd(7 downto 4) := bcd(7 downto 4) - 3;
                end if;
            if bcd(11 downto 8) > 7 then
                bcd(11 downto 8) := bcd(11 downto 8) - 3;
            end if;
            if bcd(15 downto 12) > 7 then
                bcd(15 downto 12) := bcd(15 downto 12) - 3;
            end if;
            if bcd(19 downto 16) > 7 then
                bcd(19 downto 16) := bcd(19 downto 16) - 3;
            end if;
            if bcd(23 downto 20) > 7 then
                bcd(23 downto 20) := bcd(23 downto 20) - 3;
            end if;
            -- report "i = " & integer'image(i) & LF & HT &  -- DEBUG
            --     "prior sub3 bcd = " & to_string (tbcd) & LF & HT & -- DEBUG
            --     "after sub3 bcd = " & to_string (bcd); -- DEBUG
        end loop;
        bcd(0) := inp(0);  -- An odd binary produces an odd decimal value
        return bcd;        -- the algorithm loses the LSB
    end function;

    signal cp: sfixed(20 downto -19) := to_sfixed(174334.738295,20,-19);
begin
BCD_CONVERT:
    process (cp)
        variable int_digits:    unsigned(27 downto 0);
        variable frac_digits:   unsigned(23 downto 0);

        alias L6:   unsigned(3 downto 0) is int_digits(27 downto 24);
        alias L5:   unsigned(3 downto 0) is int_digits(23 downto 20);
        alias L4:   unsigned(3 downto 0) is int_digits(19 downto 16);
        alias L3:   unsigned(3 downto 0) is int_digits(15 downto 12);
        alias L2:   unsigned(3 downto 0) is int_digits(11 downto 8);
        alias L1:   unsigned(3 downto 0) is int_digits(7 downto 4);
        alias L0:   unsigned(3 downto 0) is int_digits(3 downto 0);
        alias R5:   unsigned(3 downto 0) is frac_digits(23 downto 20);
        alias R4:   unsigned(3 downto 0) is frac_digits(19 downto 16);
        alias R3:   unsigned(3 downto 0) is frac_digits(15 downto 12);
        alias R2:   unsigned(3 downto 0) is frac_digits(11 downto 8);
        alias R1:   unsigned(3 downto 0) is frac_digits(7 downto 4);
        alias R0:   unsigned(3 downto 0) is frac_digits(3 downto 0);
        variable scp:           sfixed(20 downto -19);
        variable sign:          character;
    begin
        if cp < 0.0 then
            scp := "-"(0.0, cp)(20 downto -19);  -- change sign, slice length
            sign := '-';
        else
            scp := cp;
            sign := ' ';  -- no sign instead of '+'
        end if;
        report LF & HT & "             cp = " & to_string(cp) &
               LF & HT & "absolute val cp = " & to_string(scp);
        report LF & HT & "slv int = " & to_string(to_slv(scp)(38 downto 19))
               & " slv frac = " & to_string(to_slv(scp)(18 downto 0));
        -- leave off sign bit:
        int_digits := doubledabble_20bit(to_slv(scp)(38 downto 19));
        report "int_digits = " & to_string (int_digits);
        -- 55 logic cells following mspping and reduction:
        frac_digits := fracdabble_19bit(to_slv(scp)(18 downto 0)); 
        report "frac_digits = " & to_string (frac_digits);
        -- R6 = "0000"

        report "result   = " & sign &
                integer'image(to_integer(L6)) &
                integer'image(to_integer(L5)) &
                integer'image(to_integer(L4)) &
                integer'image(to_integer(L3)) &
                integer'image(to_integer(L2)) &
                integer'image(to_integer(L1)) &
                integer'image(to_integer(L0)) &
                '.' &
                integer'image(to_integer(R5)) &
                integer'image(to_integer(R4)) &
                integer'image(to_integer(R3)) &
                integer'image(to_integer(R2)) &
                integer'image(to_integer(R1)) &
                integer'image(to_integer(R0));
    end process;

MORE:
    process
    begin
        wait for 20 ns;
        cp <= "-"(cp)(20 downto -19);  -- change sign, slice length
        wait for 20 ns;
        cp <= to_sfixed(-307.83929,20,-19);
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

when analyzed, elaborated and simulated produces:

> ```
> ghdl -a --std=08 iopertyki.vhdl
> ghdl -e --std=08 iopertyki
> ghdl -r --std=08 iopertyki
> iopertyki.vhdl:112:9:@0ms:(report note):
>                cp = 000101010100011111110.1011110100000000111
>   absolute val cp = 000101010100011111110.1011110100000000111
> iopertyki.vhdl:114:9:@0ms:(report note):
>   slv int = 00101010100011111110 slv frac = 1011110100000000111
> iopertyki.vhdl:118:9:@0ms:(report note): int_digits = 0000000101110100001100110100
> iopertyki.vhdl:121:9:@0ms:(report note): frac_digits = 011100111000001010010101
> iopertyki.vhdl:124:9:@0ms:(report note): result   =  0174334.738295
> iopertyki.vhdl:112:9:@20ns:(report note):
>                cp = 111010101011100000001.0100001011111111001
>   absolute val cp = 000101010100011111110.1011110100000000111
> iopertyki.vhdl:114:9:@20ns:(report note):
>   slv int = 00101010100011111110 slv frac = 1011110100000000111
> iopertyki.vhdl:118:9:@20ns:(report note): int_digits = 0000000101110100001100110100
> iopertyki.vhdl:121:9:@20ns:(report note): frac_digits = 011100111000001010010101
> iopertyki.vhdl:124:9:@20ns:(report note): result   = -0174334.738295
> iopertyki.vhdl:112:9:@40ns:(report note):
>                cp = 111111111111011001100.0010100100100100010
>   absolute val cp = 000000000000100110011.1101011011011011110
> iopertyki.vhdl:114:9:@40ns:(report note):
>   slv int = 00000000000100110011 slv frac = 1101011011011011110
> iopertyki.vhdl:118:9:@40ns:(report note): int_digits = 0000000000000000001100000111
> iopertyki.vhdl:121:9:@40ns:(report note): frac_digits = 100000111001001010010000
> iopertyki.vhdl:124:9:@40ns:(report note): result   = -0000307.839290
> ```

Demonstrating proper conversion.

Without knowing anything about your LCD display it didn't seem practical to attempt to map the BCD digits to it.

These transformations from sfixed values to BCD digits represent thinking in hardware versus thinking in terms of machine instructions. If the need to reduce space isn't satisfied by the dabbles, using clocked shift registers can decrease the size further, reducing the requirement for add3 or sub3 cells trading off with a small state machine.  That can work because of optical persistence both in how eyes and LCD displays work. You simply can't see things that don't persist for some small number of milliseconds.

Comment: Great effort. Let's hope this solves the asker's problem.